Should there be small holes in the sides of ovens?
There are small holes in both my ovens in my new cooker. The insulation is showing. Is that normal?

Where is the hole?  They're usually near one of the burners for a slide in stove/oven... I don't know where they'd be for a wall oven.  See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/89335/67

This question is similar to: Purpose of hole in stove leading to oven. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is mostly speculation, but it's quite possible they're mounting holes for attaching the device in a cabinet.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
